# Doctrine 2 DQL: Cannot reuse named parameter?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

I find that I cannot do something like below, notice '`:user`' is used twice

```
$query = $em->createQuery('select p from Application\Models\Project p
                           WHERE  p.owner = :user
                           OR :user MEMBER OF p.collaborators');
$query->setParameter('user', $user);
```

I get the error "`array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements`"

I can fix the problem by doing something like below instead

```
$query = $em->createQuery('select p from Application\Models\Project p
                           WHERE  p.owner = :user
                           OR :user1 MEMBER OF p.collaborators');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use ?X you can do that.

```
$query = $em->createQuery('select p from Application\Models\Project p
                           WHERE  p.owner = ?0
                           OR ?0 MEMBER OF p.collaborators');
$query->setParameters(array($user));
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the ? syntax with named, as opposed to numbered,  parameters too?